# C# Filter Datagridview with 2 or more list of textbox to search

Tags: c#, datagridview

to print my report I need to search few materials with the same material TYPE and Date of delivery etc.

so I decided to create a new form named "REPORTS" then inside it i added 4 labels and 2 textbox and 2 DateTimePicker and 1 button and 1 DataGridView

**label names:**

```
label1 = "Material type:"
label2 = "Material Class" 
label3 = "start Date"
label4 = "end Date"
```

**TEXTBOXS**

```
textbox1="material Type"
textbox2="material class"
```

**DATETIMEPICKER**

```
datetimepicker1="Start date"
datetimepicker2="End date"
```

**BUTTON**

```
button1="SEARCH"
```

**DATAGRIDVIEW**

```
DataGridView1="myDataGrid"
```

**my database**

```
 void DGview()
    {

    string Constring = "datasource = localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=mysqlpassword";
                    MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(Constring);
                    MySqlCommand cmddatabase = new MySqlCommand("select * from albany1_b1l1.civil_materials;", conDatabase);



                try
                {
                    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmddatabase;
                    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                    bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                    myDataGrid.DataSource = bSource;
                    sda.Update(dbdataset);



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

    }
```

then I added it to public report()

```
 public Reports()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        datagridviewONE();
    }
```

here's the **PROBLEM**

in the `button1`

```
 private void SEARCH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = myDataGrid.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "material_class,material_type,last_delivery_date like '%" + m_class.Text + "%','%" + m_type.Text + "%','%" + start_date.Text + "%'";
        myDataGrid.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

no error but I always receive a warning that is pointing to this codes

```
bs.Filter = "material_class,material_type,last_delivery_date like '%" + m_class.Text + "%','%" + m_type.Text + "%','%" + start_date.Text + "%'";
```

what do you think is the problem?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: im not sure this line will work `bs.Filter = "material_class,material_type,last_delivery_date like '%" + m_class.Text + "%','%" + m_type.Text + "%','%" + start_date.Text + "%'";`

i think you need to specify each filter property separately like any SQL statement.

so it would be `bs.Filter = "material_class like '%" + m_class.Text + "%' OR material_type like '%" + m_type.Text + "%' OR last_delivery_date like '%" + start_date.Text + "%'";`

Answer (score 1):

`bs.Filter = "material_class,material_type,last_delivery_date like '%" + m_class.Text + "%','%" + m_type.Text + "%','%" + start_date.Text + "%'";`

change to

```
 bs.Filter = "material_class like '%" + m_class.Text + "%' and 
 material_type '%" + m_type.Text + "%' and 
 last_delivery_date '%" + start_date.Text + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem thank you "tofu" for helping me
here's the code

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = myDataGrid.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "material_description like '%" + m_description.Text + "%' AND material_type like '%" + m_type.Text + "%'";
        myDataGrid.DataSource = bs;
```

instead of using OR i use AND

Comment: am also post that answer did you check it